# Android TV - How to create folder and write file on removable SDCard

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-tv

My app need to create new folder and write file on a removable SDcard. With Android 7 - 9, I can do it after request SDcard permission using an access intent as below:

```
val sdCard = File(sdCardRootPath)
    val storageManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolume(sdCard)

    try {
        storageVolume?.createAccessIntent(null)?.let {
            ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(
                activity,
                it,
                StorageAccessManager.REQUEST_CODE_REMOVEABLE_PERMISSION,
                null
            )
        }
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(
            activity,
            R.string.error_no_permission_activity_handler,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        Timber.e(e)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.error_generic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Timber.e(e)
    }
```

but on Android 10 (Q), it will immediately finish with a result code of RESULT_CANCELED as the document states. I've tried with SAF api (below code, to request permission) but it does not exist on Android TV, exception threw, no activity handler.

```
activity.startActivityForResult(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE),
            intentRequestCode
        )
```

On Android 5 - 6, I tried but fail too.

How can I create, write and delete file/folder on SDcard for Android TV 5-6 and 10+? Please help!

Edit: I meant above codes are to request SDcard permission before creating folder or writing file to SDcard but all are fail.

Comment: `I can do it using an access intent as below:` That intent does not create a file or write to file.

Comment: `val sdCard = File(sdCardRootPath)` ` What is sdCardRootPath?

Comment: Your intent is also SAF.

Comment: `it will immediately finish with a result code of RESULT_CANCELED ` On Android 10 that is normal behavior for non TV too. Read the docs.

Comment: @blackapps I edited, above code is to request SDcard permission before writing file. But on Android TV 10, no activity handles that SAF intent, and for the "access intent" it just return RESULT_CANCEL so I don't have WRITE permission to SDcard on TV (Android 10).

Comment: You told nothing new. You only repeated yourself. Please reread my answers.

Comment: In short, on Android 10 on TV device, request SDcard WRITE permission with SAF and Access Intent using above codes are all fail. How can I get SDcard WRITE permission on Android TV 10?

Comment: Your intent does not ask for a write permission. Only for access. Maybe only read access, i dont know exactly. I read before that SAF is not wel implemented on Android-TV. Maybe you can use classic file code in app specific directory of removable micro SD card. You were talking the whole time of removable card?

Comment: Yes, with "Access Intent" request (TV version 7 - 9), after user granted access, I can write file to removable SDcard `/storage/0249-4c57/`. My app needs to work on the whole SDcard, not just app specific directory. :(

Comment: I dont know Android-TV and i am pretty amazed that you can write to removable card below Android Q. Not possible with normal Android since Android KitKat. Only with SAF.